# How can I set the default photo effect in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

How can I set the default photo effect in Microsoft Word 2010?

Is it possible in Word 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The pull down menu is located here:

```
File > Options > Advanced > Cut, copy, and paste > Insert/paste pictures as:
```

Reference:

- http://www.worldstart.com/change-the-default-text-wrap-settings-in-word/

Comment: It is the `text wrapping` not the `photo effect` as the OP. Thanks anyway!